# XML validation in Azure Data Factory

Tags: xml, azure, xsd, azure-data-factory

I am trying to use XSD validation in Azure Data Factory copy activity (with XML as source). I have an external XSD file.
I am also trying to understand how it can be used in Azure Data Factory. In the copy activity, under the Validation type section there are two options XSD and DTD. But, it does not have any way to specify any external file as XSD.
The documentation is also not clear about this.  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-xml). This is what the official doc says:

```
XML schema validation:
You can choose to not validate schema, or validate schema using XSD or DTD.
When using XSD or DTD to validate XML files, the XSD/DTD must be referred inside the XML 
files through relative path
```

I am confused about the second point here.

What do they mean by "XML must be referred inside the XML files"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it says, we should reference the XSD file(use relative path) in the source xml file.

For example:
In the ADF I set a Copy activity:
[image]
Here my xml file and xsd file are in the same folder and as follow:
[image]

In the order.xml, use `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="order.xsd"` to specify the xsd file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>  
<order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="order.xsd">  
          <orderItem>43546533</orderItem>
          <orderItem>53546533</orderItem>
          <orderItem>73546533</orderItem>
          <orderItem>93546533</orderItem>
          <orderItem>43546533</orderItem>
          <orderItem>73546533</orderItem>
          <orderItem>03546533</orderItem>
          <orderItem>33546533</orderItem>
          <orderItem>43216533</orderItem>
          <orderItem>1246533</orderItem>
          <orderItem>4466533</orderItem>
</order>
```

order.xsd:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">  
    <xsd:element name="order">  
       <xsd:complexType>  
         <xsd:sequence>  
            <xsd:element name="orderItem" type="xsd:string"  maxOccurs="10"/>  
         </xsd:sequence>  
      </xsd:complexType>  
    </xsd:element>  
</xsd:schema>
```

In my case, when the order.xml doesn't meet my verification rules, it will fails:
[image]

Hope my answer is helpful to you!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out. Are you using blob storage? Do I need to place the XSD file also in the same path inside the storage account as the source file?

Comment: I'm using data lake gen2 storage. It is no need to place the XSD file in the same path, just relative path.

Comment: @JosephXu Thanks for posting. But how can you have XSD validation when you don't control the XML? We get the XML from an external source, and it does not have the xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation so how can we validate against our XSD?

Comment: @SteveC , I think we can use `xsi:schemaLocation="yourURL1 xxxx.xsd"` in the xml file. And  in the xsd file we can use `targetNamespace="yourURL1"`. Can this [document](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_schema.asp) answer your question?But only reference by relative path is supported.

Comment: @JosephXu Thanks for the response. My issue is the XML's we get are fixed, so they don't have the schema section in them. The Data Factory validation has what seems to me to be a major limitation that the XML has to have the value of the schema in it. We do XSD validation in Logic Apps, and in there you just specify the XML and the XSD to validate it against.

Comment: @SteveC Sorry, I have limited knowledge of xml, can you share your question in the community? Let everyone discuss this issue together.